# launch the emulator, I only see the black window with the string 'ANDROID", and no more desktop and applications show up

Tags: emulation

I download the Android code and "make sdk" to build out my own SDK, but the emulator from this SDK does not work well -- it only shows the black window with the "ANDROID" string, but I can't see any desktop picture or any applications. what's wrong here? anyone could please provide me a hint? Thanks a lot.

I use the command:

**$./emulator @jiawelin -debug all**

and the last output message is:
**emulator: android_hw_control_init: hw-control qemud handler initialized**

Answer (score 1):

It's working, just give it time. The Android emulator is ridiculously slow to start up, especially if your computer isn't the fastest. Wait for a few minutes and it will eventually load.

(I know this reply is very late, but I just had the same problem - hopefully this will be useful to anyone else who finds this question through a search engine)

Answer (score 0):

The latest emulator in tools versions 18+ have a known problems that exhibits for some. Kill the emulator and restart it with the same AVD. Give it some time to boot this second time and you should be good to go.